# Gwt java printing a contents of a scrollpanel

Tags: java, gwt, printing, panel

I'm trying to set up a print button so when the user clicks it the contents of a ScrollPanel are printed or at least put into some form so the user can print it. Not sure what would be the easiest way to do this, I've seen suggestions about using the css to remove the other items, but I'm not really sure how to do this. Any suggestions or help? I don't know where to start

Answer (score 0):

You could try to extract the dom contents of the scroll panel and append it to a pop-up window that the user can ctrl + p to print.

The CSS way of doing it is by appending a media attribute (i.e. MEDIA="print") to the scrollpanel element, but this may not be compatible in all browsers -- no support in IE8.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html

Compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#search=media

Tutorial: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way could be, setting up in your click Handler, `Window.print()` method and using `[yourPanelName].seVisible(false)` before print method, and (true) after, to regain your native GUI.